# docker command unable to find a file from a makefile but able to find it directly from the CLI

Tags: docker, make

In the terminal, once in a directory where is a `test.tex` file, I can run the following `docker` command:

```sh
$ docker run -i --rm --name latex -v "WD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest-with-cache pdflatex test
```

But, if I create a `makefile` file with the following content:

```mk
run-docker:
    docker run -i --rm --name latex -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest-with-cache pdflatex test
```

running in the terminal the following command:

```sh
$ make run-docker
```

leads to the following error:

```sh
docker run -i --rm --name latex -v "WD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest-with-cache pdflatex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `test'.
<*> test
        
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<*> test
        
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
make: *** [makefile:15 : run-docker] Erreur 1
```

How to solve this problem (which, I guess, is unrelated to `LaTeX`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable reference is wrong, you should use `$(CURDIR)` in a Makefile:

```make
run-docker:
    docker run -i --rm --name latex -v "$(CURDIR)":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app registry.gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/texlive:latest-with-cache pdflatex test
```